# heroku run error, bad URI

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I can run the application on my local mac pc.
But when I run heroku I got this error. But I have no idea...

```
zzz-ui-MacBook-Pro:backend zzz$ heroku run bundle exec rails console

Running `bundle exec rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.7525
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:176:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?):  (URI::InvalidURIError)
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:211:in `parse'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:747:in `parse'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sentry-raven-0.6.0/lib/raven/configuration.rb:96:in `server='
    from /app/config/initializers/raven.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sentry-raven-0.6.0/lib/raven.rb:62:in `configure'
    from /app/config/initializers/raven.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Please help me.
Thanks ~!!

Answer (score 3):

The error is coming from:

```
config/initializers/raven.rb
```

which looks like it has something to do with the `sentry-raven` gem, based on the stack trace lines right above that. You should check the documentation for that gem and make sure that any code in that initializer plus any environment variables are set appropriately for your production environment on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Check your config variables, particularly `DATABASE_URL` as shown [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). Also verify you used the Heroku add-ons for Postgres, Mongo, Neo4J, or whatever you're using rather than connect anything yourself.